# Flutter exclude in futurebuilder items with same id

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have api with json data:

```
{
    "@id": "/products/622",
    "@type": "Product",
    "id": 622,
    "ppStoreId": "",
    "slug": "",
    "bgColor": "#ffffff",
    "image": "1aa10b2b5a99c63292b11db3bce9669955afa7ed.jpg",
    "name": "",
    "descriptionAz": null,
    "descriptionEn": null,
    "descriptionRu": null,
    "views": 1,
    "ppRating": null,
    "expected": false,
    "active": true,
    "fixedPrice": false,
    "tags": [],
    "category": {
        "@id": "/categories/22",
        "@type": "Category",
        "id": 22,
        "slug": "",
        "bgColor": "#000000",
        "icon": "acd57416324ef2f00da0aa460077b76637403015.svg",
        "nameAz": "",
        "nameEn": "",
        "nameRu": ""
    },
    "store": "34"
}
```

I need exclude or hide items with same store id 34, but need show only first. I have not found a single example of how to do this with Flutter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [fold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html) for this case. Iterate through all items and only add the items if it has not the store id 34 or if it is the first store with the id 34.

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> noDuplicateData = jsonData
      .fold(<Map<String, dynamic>>[],
          (List<Map<String, dynamic>> previous, Map<String, dynamic> current) {
    // Check if store id is not 34 or if it is the first one
    if (current['store'] != 34 ||
        !previous.any((data) => data['store'] == '34')) {
      previous.add(current);
    }
    return previous;
  });
```

To get only the first duplicate you can do it like that.

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> noDuplicateData = jsonData
      .fold(<Map<String, dynamic>>[],
          (List<Map<String, dynamic>> previous, Map<String, dynamic> current) {
    if (!previous.any((data) => data['store'] == current['store'])) {
      previous.add(current);
    }
    return previous;
  });
```

Comment: Looking good, but if store id is dynamic and have other duplicate?

Comment: So you want to remove all duplicates and only have the first one?

Comment: Great solution, thank you, u save my time with google